# Want new divs to push down older divs dynamically

Tags: ajax, html

I have 3 divs parallel to each other holding some information. I want three new divs, in the same position as the previous ones (refer image), take the position of the last ones while pushing the same downwards.

I want this action to happen dynamically i.e. when someone enters information on the back-end module, the more recent information takes place of the older one.

I am pretty new to Ajax and jQuery but I am sure this is the way to go. Can someone please direct me to a suitable direction?

Image: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/4149/us56.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Ajax and jQuery can be the way to go.

Simplest solution is probably to put the three blocks into one div and call
`$("#parent-div").prepend();`
on it. You can arrange the blocks how you want using CSS

```
<div id='parent-div'>
    <div class="col left">Hello World</div>
    <div class="col">Hello World</div>
    <div class="col">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Tried it out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrVY7/71/), just have a look.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

example:

```
$('<div>new div</div>').insertBefore('#divName');
```